# Prove that a closed ball is closed without using complement

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. The set $\{x \in X: d(x,x_0) \le r\}$ is a closed set.

My text have not introduced the property that if $E$ is closed in $X$, then $X \setminus E$ is open in $X$. So I am trying to prove in a different way.

My text defines a close set to be the set which contains its boundary. In addition, I know that if $E$ is closed, then for every convergent sequence in $E$, its limit also lies in $E$.

How can I use this definition and property to prove this?

Comment: Well, what do you think the boundary of the set is?  Consider if $d(x,y) =r$ and you take a ball around $y$ .... what can you say about the ball?

Comment: How do you *define* the boundary of a set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the triangle inequality between $x_0$, a sequence $y_n$, and its limit $y$:
$$
d(y, x_0) \leq d(y, y_n) + d(y_n, x_0) \leq d(y, y_n) + r
$$
and use the convergence of $y_n$ to $y$.

Answer (score 0):

The boundary of a closed ball of radius $r$, a sphere of the same radius and center, is indeed contained in the ball.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x_n \to x$ where all $x_n \in D(p,r):=\{x: d(x,p) \le r\}$ for some $p \in X, r>0$.

I claim that $x \in D(p,r)$, because if $x \notin D(p,r)$ we have $d(x,p)>r$ and we define $\varepsilon = d(x,p)-r >0$ and by convergence:

$$\exists N: \forall n \ge N: d(x_n, x) < \varepsilon\tag{1}$$

and then note that, taking $(1)$ for $n=N$ and using that $x_N \in D(p,r)$ (so $d(x_N,p) \le r$) we have by the triangle inequality:

$$d(x, p) \le d(x_N,x) + d(x_N,p) < d(x_N,p) + \varepsilon \le r + \varepsilon = d(x,p)$$

and $d(x,p) < d(x,p)$ is a contradiction. So $x \in D(p,r)$ as well and the set is (sequentially) closed.